# How to grant drop table/function privileges to a role in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I want to grant `drop` privileges on all tables and functions (not only those owned by the user) in certain schema of a specific database to a specific role. However, `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` is not enough and I didn't find how to do without making the role a superuser - superuser has rights over other databases on the same server, which is not what I want. I wouldn't mind superuser privileges limited to a specific database, but I'm not sure how to do it.

My code:

```
CREATE USER _administrator PASSWORD 'pwd12345';
CREATE ROLE administrator NOLOGIN ADMIN _administrator;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "myDB" TO administrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO administrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO administrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO administrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO administrator;
```

`administrator` is the group of `myDB` database administrators, `_administrator` is the most powerful role my client app will be able to log in as.

What I did miss or do wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only the **owner** (and superusers) can drop objects. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

> The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is
>   not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and
>   cannot be granted or revoked. (However, a similar effect can be
>   obtained by granting or revoking membership in the role that owns the
>   object; see below.) The owner implicitly has all grant options for the
>   object, too.

So, make `administrator` ***own*** such objects that users should be able to drop.

```
ALTER FUNCTION foo() OWNER TO administrator;
ALTER TABLE foo      OWNER TO administrator;
```

And you remembered to actually grant group membership, right?

```
GRANT administrator TO _administrator;
```